# How do you enable a UIButton in a different view controller?

Tags: swift, uikit

I have a UIButton in `MyViewController` called `MyButton`:

```
    let myButton: UIButton = {
   let button = UIButton()
    button.isEnabled = false
    return button
}()
```

I can't seem to figure out how to enable this button in another view controller. I tried doing this:

```
class MyOtherViewController: UIViewController {
func enableButton() {
    let upload = MyViewController()
    upload.myButton.isEnabled = true
}
```

}

but the button was not enabled.

It seems super simple, but I can't figure it out... Thanks in advance!

Comment: Could you give more context to the question. Why do you need to enable a button from another view controller? Also have you tried passing data from view controllers and then using a conditional.

Comment: @Xander I need to enable a button in another view controller because I want to enable the button only when a background process finishes uploading to my server. The background process is in a different view controller.

Comment: @Xander well I took your advice and I ended up solving my problem by passing some data into my view controller and using a conditional, but I am still curious how I am able to do this if anyone can help?

Comment: You need to access the instance of the view controller that is already in use. In your code, you are creating a new view controller.